# AMPL: Constraint optimization not planning over time as expected in LP Solver

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, ampl, lpsolve

I'm trying to build a constraint optimization model using the LP solver with AMPL(.mod) as the language.

The context is a factory that receives several orders that then go through several machines (operations) in the production process.

The operations in the orders are constrained by the daily maximum capacity of each machine.

The goal is to take as much orders, each day, that will maximize the capacity of the machines.

My code looks like this:

```
  set orders;
  param machines;
  param Planning_period;

  var order_accepted{t in 1..Planning_period,o in orders} >= 0 binary;
  var order_operation_capacity_optimized > 0;

  maximize capacity: sum{t in 1..Planning_period, o in orders, m in 1..machines} order_operation_capacity_optimized[t,o,m];

  s.t. Available_capacity_per_day{t in 1..Planning_period, m in 1..machines}: sum{o in orders} order_operation_capacity_optimized[t,o,m] <= machine_capacity[m];

  s.t. Needed_capacity_per_operation{t in 1..Planning_period, o in orders, m in 1..machines}:order_operation_capacity_optimized[t,o,m] = capacities_reqd_per_order[o,m]*order_accepted[t,o];

  s.t. Operation_completed_1{t in 1..Planning_period, o in orders, m in 1..machines}: order_operation_capacity_optimized[t,o,m] >= capacities_reqd_per_order[o,m];

  s.t. Operation_completed_2{t in 1..Planning_period, o in orders, m in 1..machines}: order_operation_capacity_optimized[t,o,m] <= capacities_reqd_per_order[o,m]*operation_completed[t,o,m];

 s.t. Precedence_restriction{t in 1..Planning_period, o in orders, m in 2..machines}: sum{tt in 1..t-1} order_operation_capacity_optimized[t,o,m-1] + order_operation_capacity_optimized[t,o,m-1] >= capacities_reqd_per_order[o,m-1]*operation_completed[t,o,m];
```

I have data that looks like this:

```
data;
set orders := order_1 order_2 order_3;
param machines := 4;
param Planning_period := 3;

param machine_capacity:= 1 10
                          2 20
                          3 25
                          4 15;
param capacities_reqd_per_order:     1         2     3   4 :=
     order_1                         7         6            4           3  
     order_2                         4         1            3           2
     order_3                         2         1            5           2;
```

The code runs without bugs but not the desired result.

The result output is:

[image]

As seen above, the model is replicating results for time_1 throughout the planning period. 
I would expect it to accept order 2 in time_2 after it processed order_1 and order_3 in time_1.

What can I do to correct this replication?

Sorry for the long post, tried to give as much clarity as possible.

I'm open to writing the code in R, if anyone can guide me.

- EDIT:

I have added constraints to impose precedence restrictions on the operations per order.

Comment: There is no sequencing and no demand in the model.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen I'm new to AMPL but I assumed that the the constraint on non-violation of the maximum machine capacity sets the demand. On sequencing, indeed I have not incorporated that. How do you suggest I move from here?

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen I've edited the main post to add a constraint to impose operation precedence restrictions.